# performSelectorOnMainThread not calling

Tags: ios, methods, call, appdelegate, performselector

My application's delegate is calling the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method just fine. Inside this method there is a line:

```
[viewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(initTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Now, the initTimer method in my view controller is not being called, even when the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is being called. Why?

I didn't have this problem before, but now that I'm updating my app to use storyboards instead of the now-not-working xibs, the `initTimer` is not being called as this line should do.

Here is the full `didFinishLaunching`... code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch   
    [application setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    //[viewController performSelector:@selector(initTimer)];
    NSLog(@"Handled");
    [viewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(initTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    return YES;
}
```

The old perform selector is still there for testing, and the `NSLog` call is how I know that the method was called. I have a similar `NSLog` call in the initTimer method, and that's how I know it's not being called.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that `viewController` is not `nil` at the time you make that call? I do not see it initialized anywhere.

Comment: Yes because it's responding to other interactions (for example pressing a button on the UI and giving the correct response), but it's just not having this method called.

Comment: That doesn't say anything about whether that particular variable is `nil` or not. The object may very well *exist*, but the `viewController` variable could still be `nil`...

Comment: It is nil in this situation, but another instance is being initialized (not the initTimer method) because it is part of the storyboard? In that case, my question would be, how do I connect the storyboard initialized viewcontroller to this variable?

Comment: Also, why is it suddenly nil? It wasn't before.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed it.

Here's what I forgot. Being that I'm using Storyboards, my appDelegate shouldn't look like the above anyway. It should really look like what Apple shows [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/index.html). So that's what I did.

But afterwards, in order to get the initTimer method to call correctly I need to put the following in the viewController's own viewDidLoad method:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(initTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

And poof! It worked. Thank you all for helping. I really appreciate it. :)